# GitHub Action "set-env" result in "No such file or directory"

Tags: github, github-actions

Trying to set an env var based on the current commit SHA that will later be used as a filename. I've tried numerous variations of "set-env", with a dynamic value or not and each time the build fails with:

```
 Setup Additional Environment Variables0s
 ##[error]No such file or directory
 Run echo ::set-env name=TEST_FILE::test-${GITHUB_SHA}
   echo ::set-env name=TEST_FILE::test-${GITHUB_SHA}
   shell: /bin/bash -e {0}
 ##[error]No such file or directory
```

---

I am referencing from the Workflow docs: https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable

```
steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2
  - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
    with:
      node-version: ${{ matrix.node }}

  - name: Setup Additional Environment Variables
    run: echo ::set-env name=TEST_FILE::test-${GITHUB_SHA}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `github` context to get *sha* value. Here is the configuration that works for me:

#### .github/workflows/test.yml

```yaml
name: Test

on: push

jobs:
  test:
    name: Test env var
    timeout-minutes: 5
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:      
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2.1.0
      - name: Set env var
        run: |
          echo "::set-env name=TEST_FILE_NAME::test-${{ github.sha }}"
      - name: Create file
        run: |
          mkdir temp
          cd temp
          touch $TEST_FILE_NAME
          ls -la
```

#### Result:

[image]